# EWS - Outlook Interop Synchronize

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm using ExchangeServer 2010 SP2
and Outlook 2013

First I'm saving a Mail to the Draft folder using EWS

```
EmailMessage.Save()
```

After that I'm trying to open the mail via Interop
but I'm getting a COMException that the item doesn't exist

```
        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();            
        Outlook.NameSpace mapi = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");            
        Outlook.MAPIFolder draftFolder = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);

        //Custom function to get EntryID
        string entryId = GetMessageId(email,IdFormat.HexEntryId);
        string storeId = draftFolder.StoreID;

        MailItem item = null;

        try
        {
            item = mapi.GetItemFromID(entryId, storeId);
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            //Item not found
        }
```

Is there any way to force Outlook to sync the Draft folder with the Exchange server?

I have used
`Session.SendAndRecieve(true)`

but it doesn't show any effect and I can't find any other Interop functions doing the desired thing.

EDIT: When disabling Cache-Mode everything runs fine but as soon as I turn it on I have no clue how to force it to get the Message

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either

1. wait until the sync finishes - use `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection, retrieve the first `SyncObject` object, call `SyncObject.Start` and wait for the [`SyncObject.SyncEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866270.aspx) event to fire.
2. On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author, it wraps Extended MAPI and can be used in any language), open the message in the online mode by using the `MAPI_NO_CACHE` (`0x200`) flag ([IMsgStore::OpenEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Extended MAPI or [RDOStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).`GetMessageFromID` in Redemption).